# Repeat current poly reduce function on multiple objects that are selected?

Tags: maya, mel

I'm looping through multiple objects, but the loop stops before going to the next object.

Created a loop with condition.  If condition is met, it calls a ReduceEdge() function.  Problem is it will only iterate once and not go to the next object and repeat the procedure.

```
global proc ReduceEdge()
{
    polySelectEdgesEveryN "edgeRing" 2; 
    polySelectEdgesEveryN "edgeLoop" 1;
    polyDelEdge -cv on;
}

string $newSel[] = `ls -sl`;

for($i = 0; $i < size($newSel); $i++)
{
    select $newSel[$i];
    int $polyEval[] = `polyEvaluate -e $newSel[$i]`;
    int $temp = $polyEval[0];

    for($k = 0; $k < $temp; $k++)
    {    
        string $polyInfo[] = `polyInfo -fn ($newSel[$i] + ".f[" + $k + "]")`;
        $polyInfo = stringToStringArray($polyInfo[$i]," ");

        float $vPosX = $polyInfo[2];
        float $vPosY = $polyInfo[3];
        float $vPosZ = $polyInfo[4];   

        if($vPosX == 0 && $vPosY == 0 && $vPosZ == 1.0)
        {   
            select ($newSel[$i] + ".e[" + $k + "]");              
            ReduceEdge();
        }
    }
}
```

Expected results: 
If I select 4 cylinders, all their edges will reduce by half the current amount.

Actual results:
When 4 cylinders are selected, only one reduces down to half the edges.  The rest stay the same.

Comment: I suspect your issue is in the line `$polyInfo = stringToStringArray($polyInfo[$i]," ");`

Perhaps it should be `$polyInfo = stringToStringArray($polyInfo[0]," ");`

Note the `$polyInfo[0]` in `stringToStringArray()`

Comment: Hi Morten!  Just wanted to respond again, and say thank you.  I tried again in a new scene with the change to the $polyInfo[0] as you suggested.  This actually did end up working.  I'm not 100% clear as to why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment did help you out, I'll try and give a more thorough explanation.

Your first loop (with `$i`) iterates over each object in your selection. This is fine.

Your second loop (with `$k`) iterates over the number of edges for the current object in the loop. So far, so good. Though, I'm wondering if it would be more correct to loop of the number of faces...

Now you ask for an array of all face normals of the face at index `$k` at object `$i`, with `` string $polyInfo[] = `polyInfo -fn ($newSel[$i] + ".f[" + $k + "]")`; ``.

If you try and print the size and values in `$polyInfo`, you'll realize you have an array with one element, which is the face normal of the particular face you queried just before. Therefore, it will always be element 0, and not `$i`, which would increases with every iteration.

I have made a Python/PyMEL version of the script, which may be nice for you to see.

```py
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.mel as mel

def reduceEdge():
    mel.eval('polySelectEdgesEveryN "edgeRing" 2;')
    mel.eval('polySelectEdgesEveryN "edgeLoop" 1;')
    pm.polyDelEdge(cv=True)


def reducePoly():
    selection = pm.ls(sl=True)

    for obj in selection:
        for i, face in enumerate(obj.f):
            normal = face.getNormal()

            if (normal.x == 0.0 and normal.y == 0.0 and normal.z == 1.0):
                pm.select(obj + '.e[' + str(i) + ']')
                reduceEdge()


reducePoly()
```

Comment: After reading your response, I realize you are correct.  It would make more sense to iterate through the faces.  This was super informative and very helpful.  Thank you for your explanation and your pymel version, which looks much cleaner and efficient.

Comment: Happy to help. Also, you should maybe watch out when comparing float with equal. There's a small chance it could be slightly off. Google float comparison for workarounds :)